# datadump mysql text \r\n in fields

Tags: mysql, dump

I have in a mysql datadump some \r\n as text in some field values.

An entry looks like this:

```
'mit festem Boden, Innenboden, Innendeckel, Aussendeckel,\r\nin Teilen!'
                                                     ^^^^
```

By importing such a string I have no carridge return in the text field of the new table I have the text "\r\n" in the field value.

How can I change the text "\r\n" into a normal carridge return.

Thanks

Comment: -r, --result-file=name Direct output to a given file. This option should be used on Windows to prevent newline "\n" characters from being converted to "\r\n" carriage return/newline sequences. The result file is created and its previous contents overwritten, even if an error occurs while generating the dump. It seems you missed that when yo do the db dump

Comment: I used the normal export function in phpmydamin. I get the same result with output as text or output in a file.

Comment: There's no "normal carridge return", it's just convention that each OS gives :-) I guess you mean `\n`

Comment: hmmh...so what I have to do??? 

I need the field values from a mysql table in the sqlite table field values. But I ever have this "\r\n" in the text. I get with phpmyadmin a string like:

INSERT INTO `testtest` (`ARTID`, `ARTNUMMER`,.....) VALUES
(1, '41016', ..... 'mit festem Boden, Innenboden, Innendeckel, Aussendeckel,\r\nin Teilen!', ....), ect.

In a sqlite tool like Firefox SQL Manager I built a query with the given result string.

But after them in the sqlite table field is no "normal carridge return" there is \r\n as text.

I need no text \r\n I need the "carridge return".